# Subscriber key related to email address and Contact Key related to Contact ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber-key, data-synchronization, accountcontactrelation

My company has created Data extensions in Marketing Cloud using the email address as related to Subscriber Key. We have recently acquire Salesforce CRM and decide to synchronise some objects (Users, Contacts, Leads and Accounts) via Marketing Cloud Connector.
How should we create the data model for the crm contacts? Relating a ContactKey to the contactId and making the email address as a primary key to avoid duplicates?
Any recommandations?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question indeed. I have written few posts concerning both  the topic of [using email address as a subscriber key, and the downsides of this practice](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud/key-decisions-in-marketing-cloud/).

Summary:

> I see four main points, when advising clients on what to use a
> Subscriber/Contact key. The details are indeed very much up to the
> individual scenario, but these points are universal. The Contact Key
> should be:
>
> 1. Unique
> 2. Persistent
> 3. Channel agnostic
> 4. (Global)
>
> I have put a parentheses around number 4, I’ll get back to that. So,
> your suggestion for using email address is failing 2 out of 3 checks.
> I don’t think I need to explain why it’s a good idea, that a Contact
> Key should be unique, so I will focus on the remaining points.

As well as on [your options once you realize the above has been a poor decision](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud/subscriber-key-migration-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).

Summary:

> You have the option of doing a Subscriber Key migration, switching
> from using email address as a Subscriber Key, to using the IDs from
> Salesforce CRM. However I suspect this would be overkill . Instead you
> should consider migrating the data within Marketing Cloud to CRM, and
> doing contact deletion on your legacy email address IDs.